# get data form 'dictionary' table

Tags: sql

I have two tables in database:

```
A: [ ID, name, SECRET_KEY]
```

examplary rows:

```
ID1, John, X
ID2, Jane, Y
```

and second ( 'dictionary')

```
B: [SECRET_KEY, explanation]
```

like:

```
X, Driver
Y, Doctor
```

i want to list all records from table A but with secret_key translated to it's explanation ( based on relation from table B).

expected result:

```
ID1, John, Driver
ID2, Jane, Doctor
```

I suppose it is very easy but i cannot figue how to do it based on wc3 tutorials :-|. I would be glad if u share with me link to good sql tutorial too.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select A.ID, A.name, B.Explaination 
from A inner Join B On A.Secret_Key = B.Secret_Key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, b.explanation
  FROM a LEFT JOIN b USING(secret_key)
```